# Android 12: on LocationChanged has invalid location?

Tags: java, android, delphi

In Android 12, my Android app (written in Delphi) can no longer access the `Jlocation` after this is supplied by `onLocationChanged`. It works fine in earlier versions.

The location system is running from a Foreground Service, which is started by the main App. `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` has been set. User "Location Allow All The Time" has been set.

It works perfectly normal in Android 10.

The Foreground Service *crashes* with this error:

```
java_vm_ext.cc:579] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: can't call double android.location.Location.getLatitude() on instance of java.util.ArrayList
06-30 06:54:13.222: A/ack.SARTrackAp(4421): java_vm_ext.cc:579]     in call to CallDoubleMethodA
06-30 06:54:13.222: A/ack.SARTrackAp(4421): java_vm_ext.cc:579]     from java.lang.Object com.embarcadero.services.SARTrackServiceProxyInterface.dispatchToNative(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[], long)
06-30 06:54:13.626: A/ack.SARTrackAp(4421): runtime.cc:669] Runtime aborting...
```

In fact, *any* call to the `JLocation` causes a crash. But, the `onLocationChanged` is generated by Android itself, so how can the supplied `JLocation` be invalid?

For example:

```pascal
procedure TLocationListener.onLocationChanged(location: JLocation);
var
  Accuracy: double;
begin
  if location.hasAccuracy then // <<< It crashes the Service here already
  begin
    LocalLog('onLocationChanged: hasAccuracy');
    Accuracy := location.getAccuracy;
    LocalLog('onLocationChanged: Accuracy='+Accuracy.ToString);
  end else LocalLog('onLocationChanged: NOT hasAccuracy');
end;
```

Comment: There was a change in Android 12 to the Location class. This issue has been resolved in Delphi 11.1

Comment: I had no idea there was any update from 11.0. I do not get notified, and the GetIt package manager claims I am up-to-date... Downloading it now, plus the Patch... Thanks Dave.

Comment: After upgrading to 11.1, my Service crashed. Managed to fix this. Now, I get a: com.embarcadero.rtl.NativeDispatchException: Invoke error: method 'onLocationChanged(Ljava/util/List;)V' not found
07-01 06:31:51.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2581):  at com.embarcadero.services.SARTrackServiceProxyInterface.dispatchToNative2(Native Method)

Comment: See updates at (https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-39566)